# Optimize below MySQL Query :

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql, I have to reduce the execution time of below update query

```
UPDATE temp_countcalculations,
(
    SELECT count(*) as insuffcounts,CRP_RefNo as ref
    FROM testsymphony7.p_education 
    WHERE testsymphony7.p_education.EducationStatusId=6 
    GROUP BY CRP_RefNo
) as icounts
SET Edu_pending=icounts.insuffcounts
WHERE temp_countcalculations.crp_refno=icounts.ref;
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: UPDATE temp_countcalculations **,** . what is this **comma** after **temp_countcalculations**

Comment: @AjeetManral, this is an implicit JOIN.

Comment: Please add the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE temp_countcalculations` AND `SHOW CREATE TABLE testsymphony7.p_education`

Comment: hi @AjeetManral , the execution time of this query is too long, i have to reduce the time so i wqas trying to find ways how it can be reduced..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited informations you provided, I'll expand as good as I can the possibilities you have (if you did not already do it)

First, let's rewrite your query:

```
UPDATE 
    temp_countcalculations t
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(*) as insuffcounts,
                CRP_RefNo as ref
            FROM 
                testsymphony7.p_education p
            WHERE 
                p.EducationStatusId = 6 
            GROUP BY 
                CRP_RefNo
        ) i ON t.crp_refno = icounts.ref
SET 
    t.Edu_pending = i.insuffcounts;
```

Good.

So, you're updating all the `t.Edu_pending` with `i.insuffcounts`, based on their reference.
There are 2 queries to optimize here.

(1):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS insuffcounts,
    CRP_RefNo as ref
FROM 
    testsymphony7.p_education p
WHERE 
    p.EducationStatusId = 6 
GROUP BY 
    CRP_RefNo
```

and (2):

```
SELECT 1 
FROM
    temp_countcalculations t
        JOIN ((1)) i ON t.crp_refno = icounts.ref
```

**Optimizing (1):**

- Ideal index on columns: `CRP_RefNo, EducationStatusId` (composite)
- Column `testsymphony7.p_education.crp_refno` `NOT NULL` and if possible, `UNIQUE`.

**Optimizing (2):**

- Ideal index on columns `temp_countcalculations.crp_refno`
- Column `temp_countcalculations.crp_refno` `NOT NULL` and if possible, `UNIQUE`.

Based on that, we might be able to go a bit further with your result of:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT 1 
FROM 
    temp_countcalculations t
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(*) as insuffcounts,
                CRP_RefNo as ref
            FROM 
                testsymphony7.p_education p
            WHERE 
                p.EducationStatusId = 6 
            GROUP BY 
                CRP_RefNo
        ) i ON t.crp_refno = icounts.ref
```

Comment: as i am new to mysql (use to code in sql server),  i am trying to find a way to update query faster.. as i mentioned update query above it is taking too much time as  you described columns are indexed...

Comment: in sql server i do not need to use group by the query if i have to update calculated counts but here in mysql same was not working

Comment: @SanketJoshi_StackOver, I need the 2 `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements I mentionned in the results as well as the `EXPLAIN` I'm asking in the question, please.

Comment: temp_countcalculations, CREATE TABLE `temp_countcalculations` (n  `Crp_Refno` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,n  `Edu_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `Emp_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `Resi_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `crim_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `ref_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `genuine_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `court_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `database_check_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `Identity_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `Total_Pending` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  `Total_Check` int(11) DEFAULT 0n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: p_education, CREATE TABLE `p_education` (n  `CRP_RefNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,n  `EducationID` int(11) NOT NULL,n  `EducationPassingYear_Auto` date DEFAULT NULL,n  `ReportId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,n  `SubordinateCheckId` int(11) DEFAULT 0,n  PRIMARY KEY (`CRP_RefNo`,`EducationID`),n  KEY `FK_ReportIdEducation_idx` (`ReportId`),n  CONSTRAINT `FK_ReportIdEducation` FOREIGN KEY (`ReportId`) REFERENCES `m_reporttype` (`ReportId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTIONn) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: @SanketJoshi_StackOver thank you. Could you please also add the explain plan?